# DI with constructor injection: Am I injecting too many services?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Using Castle Windsor for DI, in my MVC controller, I have the following:

```
    public IAccountService AccountService { get; set; }
    public IPasswordService PasswordService { get; set; }
    public IEmailService EmailService { get; set; }

    public AccountController(IAccountService accountService,
        IPasswordService passwordService, IEmailService emailService)
    {
        AccountService = accountService;
        PasswordService = passwordService;
        EmailService = emailService;
    }
```

The Account service is doing standard auth stuff, the password service is used to reset the users password, and the email service is used to send confirmation emails to the user.
My question is this: am I injecting too many services in this constructor?  Is there a significant negative impact of doing this?  If so, what is a better approach? Thx.

Comment: What is the problem? Performance?

Comment: Performance is certainly a concern, but to be clear, I have not experienced any performance degradation at this point.  I am more concerned with ensuring that I'm following good design and DI principles.

Comment: I doubt you will ever encounter a performance problem from DI. You can probably inject 100s of service in a few milliseconds. Also, splitting your service like you did is a good idea. You don't want something like a "GeneralService" class that will get bloated and become unreadable...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really a matter of opinion, but I don't think many people would have a problem with three injected services.

The rule of thumb that I learned early in my career was that more than five parameters to any method (including constructor methods) is too many.  I've since seen arguments that more than three is too many.

Injecting too many services *could* be a symptom that your class has too many responsibilities, but it might just be a symptom of what those responsibilities are.  I would personally never refactor a class for the sole purpose of injecting fewer dependencies, but would definitely see this as a reason to review the code and make sure it wasn't a symptom of some other problem.

As an aside, you should make your setters private (or even better: use a read-only member variable) for the services that are injected--generally you don't want to expose them to change from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks completely fine, aside from Phil's comment about making those setters private. In fact, there are many instances, especially with an account controller, where you're going to need a lot more than just 3 services injected.

Where you'd want to exercise caution would be with *what* you're injecting, and weather or not it belongs directly in the controller in the first place.

Other than that, as long as you're using the design pattern appropriately (which you are), you don't have anything to worry about.